# Vega-Lite single line or trail mark with multiple colours

Tags: vega, altair, vega-lite

I'm trying to plot something like a trail mark but where I can map the line colour instead of the line size. Is that possible? So far I haven't been able to achieve it.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "Google's stock price over time.",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "transform": [
    {"filter": "datum.symbol==='GOOG'"},
    {"calculate": "datum.price>400", "as": "good"}
  ],
  "mark": "trail",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"},
    "size": {"field": "good", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

This is when using size with a trail mark.

[image: This is when using size with a trail mark]

This if I map to color.

[image: This if I map to color.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lines cannot be multiple colors in Vega-Lite, but you can use a color encoding along with an impute transform to change the color of different sections of the line ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATZAgBOjQnh4qckAOLdu1McgDksMLDzd4AazCF98ZGG5VdYEaoyHRqGpCa6HiYOMCQrLpi2FpR6HzObrB08LAUkAC+6hCQeLroSrAAZty6qMkA2hoQcZWMYnjIuskRUayodLAAnqjs3GIAvJO2ZgDyM2a2BUUQYHHw6GLwrGJRyN2ReH10nozeAHzSAAyXalDosN3UlpoFGgC6y5AYuq7dEkp7T7IJTwbiaRhKajJUArKAAD2hkFayDEL1MB0BUDwg0Ie1MHVQhBqGyWTSgg0RyNR3RO3luJRxeKgAEdWOUjNEjFR6YxCawOoiKBtWEylNsxPlCmTIKCxDVKYwUWioE8wfTsbjukpuKgIST8hoDfkgA)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "Google's stock price over time.",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "transform": [
    {"filter": "datum.symbol==='GOOG'"},
    {"calculate": "datum.price>400", "as": "good"}
  ],
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative", "impute": {"value": null}},
    "color": {"field": "good", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Unfortunately this leaves breaks in the line; you can get around this by creating a background layer like this ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoAWOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATZAgBOjQnh4qckAOLdu1McgDksMLDzd4AazCF98ZGG5VdYEaoyHRqGpCa6HiYOMCQrLpi2FpR6HzObrB08LAUkAC+6hCQeLroSrAAZty6qMkA2hoQcZWMYnjIuskRUayodLAAnqjs3GIAvJO2ZgDyM2a2BUUQYHHw6GLwrGJRyN2ReH10nozeAHzSAAyXalDosN3UlpoFGgC6y5DISvDcmoxKajJUArKAAD2BkFayDEL1MBz2qigeEGhD2pg6qEINQ2SyaUEGkOhsO6J28txKqPRUAAjqxykZokYqBTGFjWB1IRQNqxqUptmJ8vkNIVwjtBp0Gvi4hhdK5uhIlHtRaCQaCoLL5aZFYj8cVvr9-oDIb8xDUiYwYXCoE8-hSUWjukpuKgAbihfjhRA3iB8kA)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "description": "Google's stock price over time.",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "transform": [
    {"filter": "datum.symbol==='GOOG'"},
    {"calculate": "datum.price>400", "as": "good"}
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative", "impute": {"value": null}}
  },
  "layer": [
    {"mark": "line"},
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {"color": {"field": "good", "type": "nominal"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

---

Edit: if you're using Altair, the equivalent would be something like this:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

alt.layer(
    alt.Chart().mark_line(),
    alt.Chart().mark_line().encode(color='good:N'),
    data=data.stocks.url
).transform_filter(
    'datum.symbol==="GOOG"',
).transform_calculate(
    good="datum.price>400"
).encode(
    x='date:T',
    y=alt.Y('price:Q', impute={'value': None})
)
```

[image]

Comment: This visually works, how can I get a definition as compact as this one using Altair? I've been trying with the `+` operator` but then it will include multiple definitions of the same line chart.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much, it's really appreciated how committed you're to this project!

Answer (score 0):

I having been thinking about this issue and have come up with another approach.
Instead of trying to fix the chart we just need to fix the data and introduce some fake rows of data where the values cross the threshold point. In my case this is 200.

So if my dataset is:

```
{"date": "2022-01-01T00:00:00", "price": 100},
{"date": "2022-01-02T00:00:00", "price": 150},
{"date": "2022-01-03T00:00:00", "price": 180},
{"date": "2022-01-04T00:00:00", "price": 270},
{"date": "2022-01-05T00:00:00", "price": 80}
```

Then we to add some fake rows :

```
{"date": "2022-01-03T00:00:00", "price": 200},
{"date": "2022-01-04T00:00:00", "price": 200},
```

To get the lines to work perfectly we need to calculate at approx what time did the line cross the threshold. We can find this out my looking at the range of start and end. If midnight was 180 and 24 hrs later it was 270 then we know it moved 90 during 24 hrs. So we just need to know how long did id take to move 20 (180 to 200).

```
{"date": "2022-01-03T00:00:00", "price": 180},
{"date": "2022-01-04T00:00:00", "price": 270},
```

[image]

I also found it was necessary to add 2 fake rows each time. One for each color otherwise vega-lite would show gaps in the chart.
Please use the javascript below to show a multi-color line chart the crosses a threshold.

Happy charting!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Vega-Lite Example</title>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@5"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="vis"></div>
<script>
// Load the data
const data = [
{"date": "2022-01-01T00:00:00", "price": 100},
{"date": "2022-01-02T00:00:00", "price": 150},
{"date": "2022-01-03T00:00:00", "price": 180},
{"date": "2022-01-04T00:00:00", "price": 270},
{"date": "2022-01-05T00:00:00", "price": 80}
];

const threshold = 200;

// Iterate through the data and add fake rows for values that cross the threshold
const newData = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
const d1 = data[i];
const d2 = data[i + 1];

// Check if the price crosses the threshold between these two data points
if ((d1.price < threshold && d2.price >= threshold) || (d1.price >= threshold && d2.price < threshold)) {
// Calculate the interpolated point where the line crosses the threshold
const t = (threshold - d1.price) / (d2.price - d1.price);
const interpolatedPrice = threshold;
const interpolatedTimestamp = new Date(new Date(d1.date).getTime() + t * (new Date(d2.date).getTime() - new Date(d1.date).getTime()));
interpolatedTimestamp.setSeconds(0); // Round to the nearest minute
const interpolatedDate = interpolatedTimestamp.toISOString();

// Add a fake data point for the interpolated value
newData.push({
date: d1.date,
price: d1.price,
color: d1.price < threshold ? 'red' : 'blue'
});

newData.push({
date: interpolatedDate,
price: interpolatedPrice,
color: d1.price < threshold ? 'blue' : 'red'
});

newData.push({
date: interpolatedDate,
price: interpolatedPrice,
color: d1.price < threshold ? 'red' : 'blue'
});

newData.push({
date: d2.date,
price: d2.price,
color: d2.price < threshold ? 'red' : 'blue'
});
} else {
// No interpolation needed, just copy the original data point
newData.push({
date: d1.date,
price: d1.price,
color: d1.price < threshold ? 'red' : 'blue'
});
}
}
// Add the last data point with the color property
const lastDataPoint = data[data.length - 1];
newData.push({
date: lastDataPoint.date,
price: lastDataPoint.price,
color: lastDataPoint.price < threshold ? 'red' : 'blue'
});

const processedData = newData.map(d => {
return {
date: new Date(d.date),
price: d.price,
color: d.color
};
});
// Test out new data source
console.log(processedData);

// Define the Vega-Lite specification
const spec = {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"values": processedData},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative", "impute": {"value": null}},
    "color": {
      "field": "color",
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {"domain": ["red", "blue"], "range": ["red", "blue"]},
      "legend": null
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
      {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "line", "strokeWidth": 3}
    }
  ],
  "config": {"legend": null}
};

// Render the chart using Vega-Embed
const embedOpt = {"mode": "vega-lite"};
vegaEmbed("#vis", spec, embedOpt);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```